# jQuery event on DOM elements working not properly

Tags: jquery, dom, events

Working on a simple calculator and a log. After getting a result after each calculation,
a new record with this result appears in a log. Clicking on a circle in this log item, the circle should turn red, i.e.toggled. But the event is successful only in turn - the first circle gets red, the second doesn't, the third does and so on. Tried everything, dont't know what's happening. Please, help [that's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgSOo.png)

```
    const mainOperationsBlock = $('.main');
    const numbersInput = $('#number-input');
    const log = $('#log');

    mainOperationsBlock.on('click', function() {
      if (numbersInput.text() === '0' && $(this).text() === '0') {
        numbersInput.text($(this).text());
      } else if (numbersInput.text().match(/[-\+\*\/]$/) && 
      $(this).text().match(/[-\+\*\/]/)) {
        numbersInput.text(numbersInput.text().substring(0, 
        numbersInput.text().length - 1) + ''+ $(this).text());
      } else if (/^0$/.test(numbersInput.text()) && 
      /[123456789]/.test($(this).text())) {
         numbersInput.text(numbersInput.text().substring(1, 
         numbersInput.text().length) + $(this).text());
      } else {
          numbersInput.text(numbersInput.text() + $(this).text());
      }
   });

    $('#erase').on('click', function() {
      numbersInput.text('0');
      numbersInput.removeClass('error');
    });

    $('#result').on('click', getResult);

    function getResult() {
      let result = eval(numbersInput.text());
      if(/[/]0/.test(numbersInput.text())) {
        numbersInput.text('ERROR');
        numbersInput.toggleClass('error');
      } else {
        $('#log').prepend(`
          <div class='log-item'>
            <span class='circle'></span>
            <p class='equation'>${numbersInput.text()}=${result} 
            </p>
            <span class='close'>&#10005;</span>
          </div>
`       );

    numbersInput.text(result);

    let logItems = $('.equation');
    logItems.each(function() {
        if(/(48)/.test($(this).text())) {
            $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
        }
    });

    $('.circle').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('red');
    });

    $('.close').on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    }
   }

   log.scroll(function() {
     console.log(`Scroll Top: ${log.scrollTop()}`)
   });
```

Comment: Do not post image of your code... Please read [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here is [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handlers for `.circle` and `.close` are inside the `getResult()` function...

So every times the function runs, a new event handler is set. That makes the `.toggleClass` execute many times. If the function runs twice, there are two event handlers... Making the toggling run twice... So it looks like not running at all.

The solution is to move those event handlers out of the `getResult()` function.

Now... those elements are dynamically created... You have to use [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

So your handlers will be:

```
$(document).on('click', '.circle', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('red');
});

$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but then the event handler is not working at all

Comment: I edited about setting event handlers on dynamically created elements.

Comment: Thank's for the edit @ValiantJoshuaBolorunduro ;)